# Illustrator CS5: suddenly every file format I "save for web & devices" is jagged

Tags: macos, adobe-illustrator, save-as

Never had this problem before, been using CS5 on my Mac OSX for months now. Suddenly in the past week every file I save for web and devices, whether it be jpeg, png or gif, is jagged. I didn't change any preferences or settings. Not sure what happened.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, you simply have to go to the *Image Size* tab in the *Save for Web* window, use the pull down option next to "Clip to Artboard" and select *Art Optimized*. That will smooth out everything.

Comment: Please [edit] and post the link to the screenshot if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar problem, my artboard image was fine, but my save for web image was not. For me Anti-Aliased Artwork was selected and it appeared that way in the artboard, but when I would Save for Web it would appear as if unselected. If unselected Anti-Aliased then my artboard would look "jagged" but my Save for Web would look fine.

To resolve the issue, I unselected Anti-Aliased, then Saved the file for Web. I then went back and selected Anti-Aliased and Saved the file for Web. I repeated these steps 3 or four times before the artboard image looked the same as the Save for Web image.

ODD!

Answer (score 0):

> every file I save for web and devices, whether it be jpeg, png or gif, is jagged.

See General Preferences, Anti-Aliased Artwork

http://rwillustrator.blogspot.com/2010/08/when-pixels-snap-antialiasing-in.html

> I didn't change any preferences or settings. Not sure what happened.

You didn't deliberately or knowingly. Cats are great aren't they.